# How to find the first thousand bytes of an image file using ddtools

Tags: command-line

Hi I am looking to find the first thousand bytes of an image file using ddtools in terminal.
Ubuntu
Can anyone help please.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The basic command structure is as follows:

```
dd if=<source> of=<target> bs=<byte size> ("USUALLY" some power of 2, and usually not less than 512 bytes (ie, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, but can be any reasonable whole integer value.) skip= seek= conv=<conversion>
```

Source is the data being read. Target is where the data gets written.

Example

```
dd if=<source> of=<destination> bs=1024 count=1
```

you have more example [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find using `head` simpler. It is also safer since a mistake with `dd` can have serious consequences (mixing `if` and `of` for example). To use `head`, do:

```
head -c 1kB image.jpg > newfile
```

Or, depending on what you want:

```
head -c1K image.jpg > newfile
```

From `man head`:

```
   -c, --bytes=[-]K
          print the first K bytes of each  file;  with  the  leading  '-',
          print all but the last K bytes of each file

   K may have a multiplier suffix: b 512, kB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M
   1024*1024,  GB 1000*1000*1000, G 1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E,
   Z, Y.
```